# Javafx GUI doesn't show up

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

Hello I'm a new learner of javaFx fxml and i'm testing table view with fxml.But netbeans show no error in my code and i can't run my GUI application.

My code of FXMLDocument.fxml is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <?import java.lang.*?>
        <?import java.util.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

        <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="359.0" prefWidth="473.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="table.FXMLDocumentController">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
              <TableView fx:id="tableview" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="90.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="93.0" text="Id" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="106.0" text="Name" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
```

And this is a fxml controller code.

```
package table;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author pyaephyohlaing
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    //the table's view and columns
    @FXML
    TableView<Person>tableview;
    @FXML
    TableColumn id;
    @FXML
    TableColumn name;

    //the table data
    ObservableList<Person>data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //setup the table data
    id.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person,Integer>("id")
    );
    name.setCellFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name")
    );

    data.add(new Person(1,"Mg Mg"));
    tableview.setItems(data);
    System.out.println("hello");
    }    

}
```

Here is Person class code. (Person.java)

```
package table;
import javafx.beans.property.*;

// a class that represents the person data to add into the table view
public class Person {

//a variable that represent the column data neeed to be JavaFx properties(i.e SimpleStringProperty)   
//sets as the JavaFx table data property   
    public SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    public SimpleStringProperty name;

    public Person(Integer id,String name) {
        System.out.println("Hee");
        this.id=new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.name=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

//getter method
    public Integer getId() {
        return  id.get();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

}
```

This is the main Table.java code.

```
package table;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author pyaephyohlaing
 */
public class Table extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And when i run my project,GUI is not appeared and it shows many errors like that.

> Executing
>   /Users/pyaephyohlaing/NetBeansProjects/table/dist/run1649041788/table.jar
>   using platform
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
>   Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot
>   be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures  at
>   javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:98)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.getCell(TableRowSkin.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.getCell(TableRowSkin.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.createCell(TableRowSkinBase.java:698)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.recreateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:692)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:146)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.(TableRowSkin.java:64)
>     at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
>     at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:859)   at
>   javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9153)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
>     at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1079)     at
>   javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)  at
>   javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)   at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1646)     at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1720)    at
>   javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:846)    at
>   javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
>     at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)  at
>   javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)     at
>   javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)   at
>   table.Table.start(Table.java:27)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   Exception running application table.Table Java Result: 1 Deleting
>   directory
>   /Users/pyaephyohlaing/NetBeansProjects/table/dist/run1649041788
>   jfxsa-run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

I have no idea what's wrong with my code and can anyone help me to fix the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the FXMLDocumentController you set the cell factory for Id when I think you meant to set the cellValueFactory for name.

Change:

```
id.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name")
);
```

To:

```
name.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name")
);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.But the run time error is still showing....GUI doesn't show up!! :(

Comment: @PyaePhyoHlaing please pay attention on diff: setCellFactory and setCellValueFactory also..

Comment: @PyaePhyoHlaing this is the answer to your question, checked the code on my IDE too. I wanted to remark that we should declare generic classes with their respective types: `TableColumn<Person, Integer> id` instead of `TableColumn id`. Improving readingness.